# How installer script extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`?

Tags: setup-script, install-script, upgrade-script

Lot of time, I heard that installer script, upgrade script, and data script files are extending `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` (default case). When we make a look on any of these file, there is no hint for this. For example, an installer script somewhat look like this.

```
#FILE : app/code/<any_code_pool>/<AnyNameSpace>/<AnyModuleName>/sql/<any_script_setup>/install-x.x.x.php
$installer =  $this;
$installer->startSetup();

//some stuffs here

$installer->endSetup();
```

As you can see, the file does not specify any class or not extending any class explicitly. And then also several tutorial says that `$this` is an instance of `resource setup class`.  How it is possible?

Can you guys give some hints about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all starts in `Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules`. Actually it starts higher in the stack but you are interested on this.
In this method there is this line:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates();
```

And the method `applyAllUpdates` looks like this:

```
static public function applyAllUpdates()
{
    Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(true);
    self::$_hadUpdates = false;

    $resources = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources')->children();
    $afterApplyUpdates = array();
    foreach ($resources as $resName => $resource) {
        if (!$resource->setup) {
            continue;
        }
        $className = __CLASS__;
        if (isset($resource->setup->class)) {
            $className = $resource->setup->getClassName();
        }
        $setupClass = new $className($resName);
        $setupClass->applyUpdates();
        if ($setupClass->getCallAfterApplyAllUpdates()) {
            $afterApplyUpdates[] = $setupClass;
        }
    }

    foreach ($afterApplyUpdates as $setupClass) {
        $setupClass->afterApplyAllUpdates();
    }

    Mage::app()->setUpdateMode(false);
    self::$_schemaUpdatesChecked = true;
    return true;
}
```

The interesting part is this:

```
        $className = __CLASS__;
        if (isset($resource->setup->class)) {
            $className = $resource->setup->getClassName();
        }
        $setupClass = new $className($resName);
        $setupClass->applyUpdates();
```

So if you specify a specific class for the upgrade scripts that will be instantiated, otherwise `__CLASS__` (which is `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`) will be used.

And if you look for the method `applyUpdates` that is called in the code above you will end up after digging in `_modifyResourceDb` method in the same class where this code is what you are looking for

```
case 'php':
    $conn   = $this->getConnection();
    $result = include $fileName;
```

This means that the upgrade script is included in class you are using, hence you can access `$this`.

Side note: In a similar way you can access `$this` in template files. They are included in rendering method for blocks.

Comment: Oh i never knew you could make a .sql install script :)

Comment: @DavidManners I don't think someone ever did. And since ce-1.6, when the install scripts changed to use DDL table definitinos, this seams kind of a bad practice. In my opinion the support for sql files should be removed.

Comment: We had this discussion yesterday if it is there someone will try ;)

Comment: Yes. I digged upto applyAllUpdates() and saw the class instantiation. But was thinking from where this method get called. Your answer gave me the idea where it calls from. My doubt cleared. Thanks for this outstanding answer

Comment: " it starts higher in the stack but you are interested on this" :- I didn't get the meaning of this?

Comment: @programmer_rkt. It all starts in `index.php` with `Mage::run` but that was not interesting for what you asked. The updates are applied when running any page and that's where it all starts.

Comment: @DavidManners. Try it and let us know the result. :)

Comment: @Marius : Yep. Everything clear now. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Magento creates a new class and uses function *include* to insert content of the install script. Similar to .phtml files that also use $this variable and it's the block object.

See `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` and method `_modifyResourceDb`

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer please? Where it includes this class?